# PHP drop down menu list categories

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

http://postimg.org/image/5u8xrw3vh/

I want that when I select books the categories below that like product [menu, name, publisher etc] will only get Displayed  when I select books and I don't want those same categories for movies, music, etc.. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have two dropdowns and you want to populate the second drop down based on what the user selects in the first dropdown:**

```
<select id="category_dropdown">
    <option value="Movies">Movies</option>
    <option value="Books">Books</option>
</select>

<select id='product_dropdown'></select>
```

**To do this, use the following JavaScript:**

```
var product_menu = [];

//Books
product_menu["Books"] = [
    "Author",
    "Title",
    "Publisher"
];

//Movies
product_menu["Movies"] = [
    "Actor",
    "Producer",
    "Movie Title"
];

//Setup listener on the category drop-down to update the products menu
var category_dropdown = document.getElementById("category_dropdown");
category_dropdown.addEventListener("change", function(){

  var product_dropdown = document.getElementById("product_dropdown");

    //Remove all options from product menu
    product_dropdown.innerHTML = "";

    //Now add new options
    var product_items = product_menu[category_dropdown.value];

    for(var i = 0; i < product_items.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = product_items[i];
        option.value = product_items[i];
        product_dropdown.add(option);
    }
});
```

**Please mark as the answer if you find this helpful, thanks!**